# How to add a condition to existing lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Consider the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I have a method in the service layer that does:

```
public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where)
{
    return customerRepository.Get(where);
}
```

The calling code is:

```
var customer = customerService.Get(x => x.Number == number);
```

In the above method, the user searches a customer based on a property (excluding `GroupId` because this is hidden in the ViewModel). However, a user is always assigned to a group, and therefore, he is only allowed to search for customers within his group. So the `GroupId` must be added dynamically.

How can I add the `GroupId` to the `where` expression in the method above. The `GroupId` may or may not be already available in the expression.

Comment: look into [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) you can help build expressions that you can add onto your calls. This would allow you to do something like below.

```
public void DoSearch(MyViewModel vm)
{
    Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> myFilter = x => yourCurrentFilterLogic;
    var combined = myFilter.And(x => x.GroupId == vm.GroupId);   //PredicateBuilder extension method
    var customers = Get(combined);
}

public Customer Get(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> where)
{
    return customerRepository.Get(where);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the PredicateBuilder and not simply a `.Where(x => x.Id == groupID)?`

Comment: i made a better example that shows building a single expression to send to his `Get()` method that shows why I was thinking of `PredicateBuilder`. He didn't provide the code that shows his first expression, so it's not totally clear whether `PredicateBuilder` would be needed or not.

Comment: @xanatos Tried the PredicateBuilder extension. I get the exception: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities`

Comment: I've changed the  `PredicateBuilder` class as per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406952/keep-getting-the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to) and it works like a charm!