# Build a linq query based on conditional values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a large record set of people and each of those people are in a country.

I cam retrieve all people in Australia using Entity Framework with the following:

```
var people = db.People.Where(x=>x.Country == "Australia")
```

What I'm not sure how to do is to retrieve people that are in Country X or Country Y based on a set of Boolean values.

Ie:

```
bool USA = true;
bool Australia = false;
bool UK = true;
bool China = false;
```

How do I build a linq query that in this case would give me:

```
var people = db.People.Where(x=>x.Country == "USA" || x.Country == "UK")
```

Thanks

Comment: `PredicateBuilder` and a bunch of `if` statements is what you're looking for.

Comment: The problem is that there are 10 countries so quite a few permutations. -)  Was hoping for a fancy way using a Dict or something

Comment: permutations? See my answer. There are no permutations involved.

Comment: Hmm, getting [System.NotSupportedException] --- {"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."} trying to use PredicateBuilder.  Any ideas?

Comment: All good, solved with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406952/keep-getting-the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<People>();

if (USA)
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Country == "USA");
if (Australia)
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Country == "Australia");

// ...

var people = dp.People.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: I think it's likely the link to Joe's code would remain valid for a long time to come. However, the implementation is very short and IMHO would be appropriate to quote here in its entirety, or at least the `Or()` method part. That would ensure that this answer remains useful as long as the question exists.

Answer (score 1):

`PredicateBuilder` is the right answer. As an alternative, you could do something like:

```
var countries = new List<string>();

if(USA) countries.Add("USA");
if(Australia) countries.Add("Australia");
if(UK) countries.Add("UK");

// ...

var people = dp.People.Where(x => countries.Contains(x.Country));
```

This would be translated to a `WHERE IN` SQL clause

#### Update

As the comments point out, in a Linq-To-Entities (or Linq-To-SQL) scenario, it doesn't matter, but if you plan to use this for Linq-To-Objects, it'd be wiser to use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>` for performance reasons

Comment: @PeterDuniho It will be translated into SQL anyway, so type of collection doesn't matter - `Contains` will be translated into `IN` clause and never actually called.

Comment: @PeterDuniho you are right, I'll modify the answer, I was thinking of Entity Framework, not Linq-To-Objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//You can add, remove or change filters
var tempDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>
{
    {"USA", true},
    {"Australia", false},
    {"UK", true},
    {"China", false},
};
//Get relevant filters
var tempFilter = tempDictionary
                 .Where(item => item.Value)
                 .Select(item => item.Key)
                 .ToArray();
var tempPeople = db
                 .People
                 .Where(x => tempFilter.Contains(x.Country));
```